# MOQ setup function to throw exception doesn't work

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the following function signature:

```
T SomeMethod(Expression<Func<T, string>> param1, 
             , params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] items);
```

I want it to throw an exception everytime it's executed.

I tried to do the following setup:

```
myMock.Setup(x => x.SomeMethod(Moq.It.IsAny<Expression<Func<SomeClass, string>>>()))
      .Throws(new Exception());
```

Everything works find but when I arrive to this method it does't throw an exception (although the object is my mock).

I assume my setup is incorrect.

I tried many variation for a while and now I'm a bit frustrated.

I would have put more code but it is restricted. Each piece I want to upload I should  alter so excuse me for being cheap with information.

Hope it's enough and some one can assist me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like the problem is in the `params` parameter. Try adding it to the setup

```
myMock.Setup(x => x.SomeMethod(
         Moq.It.IsAny<Expression<Func<SomeClass, string>>>()),
         Moq.It.IsAny<Expression<Func<T, object>>[]>())
      ).Throws(new Exception());
```

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks a lot.

You are too quick so I can accept you're answer in only five minutes....

In the meanwhile, maybe you can assist me, how can I force the second call to do another action (return, another exception)?

Comment: You need to use SetupSequence for that